# What is the asymptotic solution to the roots of $x^n+a_1 \epsilon x^{n-1} +\cdots+ a_{n-1}\epsilon^{n-1}x+a_n \epsilon^n$?

Tags: polynomials, approximation, perturbation-theory

The polynomial I'm working with is:

$$
\lambda^n
+\frac{\epsilon}{p \ 1!}\lambda^{n-1}
+\frac{\epsilon^2}{p^2 2!}\lambda^{n-1}
+\dots
+\frac{\epsilon^{n-1}}{p^{n-1} (n-1)!}\lambda
+\frac{\epsilon^{n}}{p^n (n!)}
=0
$$

I've been scouring the internet for a method for finding it's solution, and the closest I've found is [this](http://sycon.rutgers.edu/~speer/528s17/Perturbation-DG.pdf). In the paper they only deal with polynomials with known coefficients, and a large part of their method is graphical.

Can anyone help me untagle the paper, or point in the direction of another resource which might help?

Comment: If you scale $\lambda=\epsilon\lambda_0$ you get $\lambda_0^n+\lambda_0^{n-1}/p+\ldots+\lambda_0/((n-1)!p^{n-1})+1/(n!p^n)=0$ at leading order so I'm not sure how much you'll be able to say in general.

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial above can be transformed into the exponential sum function:

$$
e_n = \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}
$$

The roots of this polynomial are known to approach the curve in the unit disk $|x e^{1-x}|=1$ for large $n$. No perturbation theory necessary.